# Resorce leak conIn never closed

Tags: java, eclipse, memory-leaks

This code is giving me a resource leak:

> conIn never closed

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

```
package homeWork;
import java.util.*;

public class MainClass 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner conIn = new Scanner (System.in);
        ShoppingBag sb = new ShoppingBag(0.06f);

        int count = 0;
        float cost = 0.0f;

        System.out.print("Enter count (use 0 to stop): ");

        count = conIn.nextInt();
        while (count < 0);
       {
           System.out.print("Enter Cost");
           cost = conIn.nextFloat();
           sb.place(count, cost);

           System.out.print("Enter count (use 0 to stop): ");
           count = conIn.nextInt();
           System.out.print(sb);

       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call `conIn.close();` on your `Scanner` object. ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()))

Comment: Thank you! that fixed it! Another question. My loop is not running the way it should. I'm trying to run a loop that stops after I enter the number 0. My statement runs only 3 times then it just prints the results which is what I really don't want.

Comment: I was trying to check mark both but it seems that I can only check mark one post?

Comment: Yes, anyway it's ok. I will try to help you with the loop thing but in the future open a new question for that

Comment: So in order for your loop to stop when the user enters `0` you can just change your `while` to `while(count != 0)` and then it will work.

Comment: Do you think I should just open a new question for that now?

Comment: Since this is very easy (and I answered it in the previous comment), I'd say you don't need the new question now

Comment: That is what I originally had on my program but for some reason it does not run an infinite amount of times until that 0 is imputed.

Comment: Umm that is very peculiar. From what I see, there is no other option for it to stop other than when **you** enter a 0. Did you try using a debugger and going through the execution of your program step-by-step? It's a very good way of detecting errors with your code

Comment: Enter count (use 0 to stop): 5
Enter Cost10.5
Enter count (use 0 to stop): 2
the bag contains 5 itemsThe retail cost of the items is = 52.5The total cost = 55.649998Enter Cost

Comment: that's what gets printed out. I'm not very familiar with the debugger

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error (tried running your code). Please try and google (read) about a debugger in your IDE (probably IntelliJ, Visual Studio or Eclipse). It will serve you **many more** times in the future. If that fails, open a new question with all the relevant details and I'm positive you'll get a solution.

Comment: I think it may be because of the other class I have in order to run my main class?

Answer (score 0):

> Closing a stream when it's no longer needed is very important — so
>   important that your program uses a finally block to guarantee that both
>   streams will be closed even if an error occurs. This practice helps
>   avoid serious resource leaks.

```
Scanner conIn = new Scanner (System.in);
```

You need to close the resource stream (System.in). After the loop-end close the stream.

```
conIn.close();
```

Comment: Thank you! that fixed it! Another question. My loop is not running the way it should. I'm trying to run a loop that stops after I enter the number 0. My statement runs only 3 times then it just prints the results which is what I really don't want.